# Jackson serialization with null

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Jackson annotations are for serialization but I cannot find the solution to have two different views with different behavior. Having the following json:

```
{
  "username": "username",
  "manager": null,
  "password": "pwd"
}
```

I'd like to have to following output in case the first view (public: no null and no sensitive information):

```
{
  "username": "username"
}
```

For the second view (internal: incoming nulls are showed sensitive information is hashed):

```
{
  "username": "username",
  "manager": null,
  "password": "hashedValue"
}
```

The problem is when the optional fields are not provided like in the following json:

```
{
  "password": "pwd"
}
```

I'd like to have an empty for public and only the hashed password in the internal view:

```
{
  "password": "hashedValue"
}
```

I have the following class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Test {
  private String username;
  private String manager;
  private String password;

  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = Md5Serializer.class)
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getManager() {
    return manager;
  }

  public void setManager(String manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
  }
}
```

This can do most what I'd like to have but it cannot make difference if a value is null because of the default value or because it's coming from the JSON.

An other approach was to use a Map inside the object:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Test {

  private Map<String, String> content = new HashMap<>();

  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = Md5Serializer.class)
  @JsonIgnore
  public String getPassword() {
    return this.content.get("password");
  }

  @JsonSetter
  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.content.put("password", password);
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getUsername() {
    return this.content.get("username");
  }

  @JsonSetter
  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.content.put("username", username);
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getManager() {
    return this.content.get("manager");
  }

  @JsonSetter
  public void setManager(String manager) {
    this.content.put("manager", manager);
  }

  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, String> getContent() {
    return this.content;
  }
}
```

In this case the problem that the password is not hashed (and the hashed value cannot be stored here).

If the getters are used and the JsonAnyGetter is removed then the incoming null cannot be serialized as the JsonInclude ignores the field. I was reading a lot that a BeanSerializerModifier can be used but that is also needed to be register in all ObjectMapper instance.

Also I'm not sure that without setting the view I'd like to have only the Public view but currently all non-null values are shown. Any idea how it can be achieved only by annotations?